# Understand koa-passport authenticate with IIFE

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, koa, iife

I recently started playing around with KoaJS and stumbled uppon `koa-passport` and I'm having a really hard time understanding this code:

```
function signinUser(req, res, next) {  
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(400).send(info);
    }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

especially in terms of IIFE. I have no idea which method is immediately invoked with the `(req, res, next)` parameters and why.

Looking at the simpliest iife example:

```
()=> {
  // code goes here...
}()
```

For me it should be passports `authenticate` method but when I look at Passports documentation http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/ it does not match.

Probably it's a dumb question but can someone explain it to me in a very simple way? I can't get my head around it :( How would this code look without any IIFE?

Comment: What appears to be happening here is that `passport.authenticate` returns a function, which is then called with the arguments `req`, `res` and `next`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Can You maybe elaborate a bit on this? How do You know this? I still can not wrap my head around it (there is nothing in the docs or I don't see it)

Comment: I've never used this library, and don't really know what is going on, but since the syntax is of the form `passport.authenticate(a, b)(x, y, z)` then the only way that won't throw an error is for `passport.authenticate(a, b)` to be a function.